# Difference between ancient greek stative aspect and latin perfective aspect

Tags: latin, greek, aspect

In greek the perfect, pluperfect and future perfect are a combination of tense (present, past and future) and the stative aspect while the perfective aspect is used in combination with the past tense to form the aorist.
In latin the perfect is a combination of the greek aorist and perfect. The latin perfect, pluperfect and future perfect all have perfective aspect.

So does the perfective in latin mean something else than in greek? Or is the meaning of the pluperfect/future perfect different? If the pluperfect and future perfect are described as having stative aspect in greek and perfective aspect in latin does that mean the perfective in latin combines the greek stative and perfective?

I dont get it thanks

Comment: The perfect stem in Greek is usually described as expressing resultative aspect, not stative. *Perfective* means the same thing in both languages, *perfect* does not.

Comment: It's an unfortunate historical accident of terminology. The Latin pluperfect and Greek pluperfect are the same aspect, but books vary in calling it "perfective aspect", "perfect aspect", or something else.

Comment: @Draconis The Greek pluperfect *doesn't* express perfective aspect, though, unlike the Latin pluperfect. It's just the past tense of the perfect.